# Magento adding configurable product to cart programmatically

Tags: magento, cart, configurable-product

I'm trying to add a configurable product to the cart, but while it's not throwing any Exceptions, the cart is still empty.

I've used this code before without problems, so I'm not sure if it's something to do with the version of Magento I'm using.

The code I'm using is:

```
   $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

   $attr = array_keys($post['sa']);

   $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
   $cart->init();

    foreach ($post['sa'][$attr[0]] as $optId){
        try {
            if (abs($post['qty'][$optId]) > 0){
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($post['product']);
                $this->getRequest()->setParam('product',$post['product']);
                $this->getRequest()->setParam('super_attribute',array(
                        $attr[0] => $optId
                    ));
                $options = array(
                    "product"=>$post['product'], 
                    "super_attribute"=>array(
                        $attr[0] => $optId
                    ),                    
                    "qty"=>$post['qty'][$optId]
                ); 


                $opts = new Varien_Object();
                $opts->setData($options);

                var_dump($opts);

                $cart->addProduct($product, $opts);
                $cart->save();

            }
        } catch (Exception $e){
            var_dump($e);
        }


    }

    $cart->save(); // save the cart
    $cart->setCartWasUpdated(true); 

$pdts = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();

    var_dump($pdts);
    die("??");
```

So I'd expect to get a cart with 6 items in it (3 products, configurable + simple), however I'm getting null instead - as you can see from the below, which also shows the $opts object I'm trying to pass:

```
    object(Varien_Object)[507]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=3)
          'product' => string '86' (length=2)
          'super_attribute' => 
            array (size=1)
              179 => string '20' (length=2)
          'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
      protected '_origData' => null
      protected '_idFieldName' => null
      protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
      protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
    object(Varien_Object)[663]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=3)
          'product' => string '86' (length=2)
          'super_attribute' => 
            array (size=1)
              179 => string '19' (length=2)
          'qty' => string '2' (length=1)
      protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
      protected '_origData' => null
      protected '_idFieldName' => null
      protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
      protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
    object(Varien_Object)[678]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=3)
          'product' => string '86' (length=2)
          'super_attribute' => 
            array (size=1)
              179 => string '17' (length=2)
          'qty' => string '3' (length=1)
      protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
      protected '_origData' => null
      protected '_idFieldName' => null
      protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
      protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
    null
    ??
```

Any help would be apprciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can add using following code.

```
try {
$product_id = '126'; 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'super_attribute' => array(
        525 => 100,
        //525 is the attribute id of size and 100 is the selected option value (small) of that attribute.  
    ),
    'qty' => 2,
);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');
//to do
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (very possible), this would only work for adding a product with custom options? I am trying to add a configurable product with super_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As life would have it, the problem was actually unrelated to adding to the cart.

There is a known 'issue' with using localhost as the hostname on Magento - plenty of other posts on here deal with that. We were working round that, but apparently it still wasn't persisting my session in Chrome, but it's working fine in Firefox.